# Where is D. Kaplan's “S5 with Quantifiable Propositional Variables” published?

Tags: reference-request

The article [Quantifiers and Quantification](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/quantification/#QuaProModLog) in Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy gives the reference below, but the article is not in the Journal of Symbolic Logic, 35.

May someone help me with finding Kaplan's article?

Kaplan, D., 1970, “S5 with Quantifiable Propositional Variables”, Journal of Symbolic Logic, 35: 355.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find another more precise citation elsewhere online as:

David Kaplan. S5 with quantifiable propositional variables. *The Journal of Symbolic Logic*, 35(2):355, 1970.

It seems possible it occurs within these pages: https://doi.org/10.2307/2270571 ("Meeting of the Association for Symbolic Logic").